# How to solve this? (Error: subversion has multiple installed versions)

Tags: macos, svn, osx-mavericks, homebrew

After I updated to the OS X Mavericks, I have problems with `svn`.

> Error: subversion has multiple installed versions

[image: Error]

Does anyone know how to solve it? Any links that will help is welcome too.

Answer (score 1):

Check your SVN Installations. Apparently you have installed SVN more than once. While updating SVN, it is recommended to remove the old one and install the new one.